# get code value in Alamofire jsonSerializationFailed

Tags: ios, json, swift

Error :

```
responseSerializationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Something looked like a 'true' but wasn't around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Something looked like a 'true' but wasn't around character 0.}))
```

I need to handle with code .I measn :

```
case .failure(let error): 

if code  == 3840 {
}
```

I need to handle this with code. If i get this code then i need to show some message. So from the above error message with my above code how can I handle that failure case with the code value?

Thanks in advance ~~

Answer (score 0):

You can get it from the response like this

```
result.response?.statusCode
```

read more about here:
https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#response-handling